# Forcing label to flow inline with input that they label

Tags: css, input, label

I need the label to stay on the same line as the input field they are labeling. I want these elements to flow like they normally would when the window resizes, i just want the label to stick to the left of the input they are labeling. How would I do that? Any ideas?

```
<label for="id1">label1:</label>
<input type="text" id="id1"/>
<label for="id2">label2:</label>
<input type="text" id="id2"/>
```

ANSWERED: Josiah Ruddell's answer was on the right path, using a span instead of div gave me the correct behavior. Thanks!

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="id1">label1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id1"/>
</span>
<span style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="id2">label2:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id2"/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

put them both inside a `div` with nowrap.

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap">
    <label for="id1">label1:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work when I tried it. It made it not wrap at all... I still want it to wrap when the window is big enough.

Comment: Oh, but this method would work with a SPAN! So what I'm actually looking for is this:

    <span style="white-space:nowrap">
     <label for="id1">label1:</label>
     <input type="text" id="id1"/>
    </span>
    <span style="white-space:nowrap">
     <label for="id2">label2:</label>
     <input type="text" id="id2"/>
    </span>

Comment: This answer is correct, but also check @Omar's answer which is without an extra div: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25416650/9868445. I like that answer more because labels are inline and so you don't lose the ability to put two or more inputs on the same line.

Comment: input most not have display:block set for it to work

Comment: Doesn't work...

Answer (score 12):

Put the `input` in the label, and ditch the `for` attribute

```
<label>
  label1:
  <input type="text" id="id1" name="whatever" />
</label>
```

But of course, what if you want to style the text?  Just use a `span`.

```
<label id="id1">
  <span>label1:</span>
  <input type="text" name="whatever" />
</label>
```

Comment: @Sebastian I disagree wholeheartedly, whoops wasn't done with my comment: the w3c spec specifies the interaction for when an input element is within a label. I assume that's because it's *intended*. "To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the LABEL element. In this case, the LABEL may only contain one control element. The label itself may be positioned before or after the associated control." http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Comment: This doesn't work when I tried it. Putting the input inside the label tag doesn't force them to wrap together.

Comment: @user366735 if you could provide a live example you can get a better answer.

Comment: Input should never be inside label- It is called label for something- out of all solutions possible, this is the wrong one. This is now how we want to code.

Comment: @AlbuquerqueWebDesign, I disagree, and so does the HTML specification, ["The label element represents a caption in a user interface. The caption can be associated with a specific form control, known as the label element's labeled control, either using the for attribute, **or by putting the form control inside the label element itself**."](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element) emphasis mine.

Comment: Although this answer is very old, but here's an example that shows it doesn't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-beaver-2ixkn?file=/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

...

<label for="id1" class="nowrap">label1:
    <input type="text" id="id1"/>
</label>
```

Wrap your inputs within the label tag

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jwB2Y/123/

The following CSS class force the label text to flow inline and get clipped if its length is more than max-length of the label.

```
.inline-label { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    float:left;     
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label for="id1" class="inline-label">This is the dummy text i want to display::</label>
    <input type="text" id="id1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did so that input didn't take up the whole line, and be able to place the input in a paragraph, I used a span tag and display to inline-block

html:

```
<span>cluster:
        <input class="short-input" type="text" name="cluster">
</span>
```

css:

```
span{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: you can put some snap so that we can understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you want they to be paragraph, then use it.

```
<p><label for="id1">label1:</label> <input type="text" id="id1"/></p>
<p><label for="id2">label2:</label> <input type="text" id="id2"/></p>
```

Both `<label>` and `<input>` are paragraph and flow content so you can insert as paragraph elements and as block elements.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't You just use:

```
label {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 24px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: jsFiddle says: Error 404
We're truly sorry, but there is no such page.