# Using Bootstrap & form validation - getting the tick image to right of the input field

Tags: jquery, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Bootstrap 3 framework & jQuery validate plugin to show errors on a form field by displaying a 'green tick' image directly to the right of each form field - it works it just shows the image just under the field rather than to the right.

I am trying to simulate the following form on this demo
http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputFirstName" style="display: none;">First Name</label>
    <?= form_input('first_name', '', "id='first_name' class='form-control {$error}'"); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputLastName" style="display: none;">Last Name</label>
    <?= form_input('last_name', '', "id='last_name' class='form-control {$error}'"); ?>
  </div>                    
</div>
```

My CSS/JS is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/includes/jquery.validate.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#checkout-form').validate({
    rules: {
        first_name: {
            minlength: 2,
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});

});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   label.valid {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('/assets/images/icons/tick.png') center center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
 }
 label.error {
 font-weight: bold;
 color: red;
 padding: 2px 8px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code use Twitter's Bootstrap 2, while your are using Twitter's Bootstrap 3. The structure of the forms has changed since TB3, see .

I think the horizontal form best fits, your needs http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal. Note labels and input are not inline by default (see: [Forcing label to flow inline with input that they label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209154/forcing-label-to-flow-inline-with-input-that-they-label))

Your example code from  http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/index.html adds a second label to the input and applies the background on this. Your code don't add the second label and applies the background on a hidden element? (i don't understand)

Example to do the same with Twitters Bootstrap 3's horizontal forms: http://bootply.com/88601

**html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail2" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**css**

```
  label.valid {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url('//alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/assets/img/valid.png') center center no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
 }
```

**javascript**

```
$('#inputEmail1').closest('.form-group').append('<div class="col-lg-1"><label class="valid">OK!</label></div>');
$('#inputEmail2').closest('.form-group').append('<div class="col-lg-1"><img src="http://alittlecode.com/files/jQuery-Validate-Demo/assets/img/valid.png" alt=">>OK!"></div>');
```

You should apply the javascript calls above on your `success:` Personal ishould prefer to add an image instead of a label.