# Binding Text Label to an Input Field so that when Google Maps moves them they move together

Tags: html, css, google-maps

Can someone please help with a the binding of a `text label` to an `input text` box.  The purpose is to implement a search box as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21412111/how-to-add-a-googlemap-search-box-to-my-customized-map).

The problem is, is that when you move a Google Control, say to place it at the top of the map, Google appears to take control of the `input box` and leaves everything else behind.  I have tried every possible technique and even [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209154/forcing-label-to-flow-inline-with-input-that-they-label) which I thought might work; but it doesn't.

Basically what I want is for this to bind:

```
<div>Search Box: <input id="pac-input" class = "search-input"></input></div>
```

**EDIT:**  Just thinking about it I could just create a label an position it near the `<input box>` but that could be a little messy and possibly hit and miss.

Comment: You need to include the label in the HTML that you place in the control.  Bind the autocomplete to the input element. Please provide a [mcve] that exhibits your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the label in the HTML that you place in the control. Bind the autocomplete to the input element.